# How can I reduce the memory required for following example (nested ‘for’ loops)

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, memory

I want to plot a convolution of two spectra. The first one is a weighted dirac comb, the second a defined function. To do this I used two nested for loops but the calculation exceed the Tex capacity (even though I increased it significantly): `TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=259000000]`.

Is there a better way to visualize the convolution of artificial functions? Or a better way to implement the given example? It is working with samples=100 but I need like 1000 to have sharp edges.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \begin{axis}[xmax=4.5,xmin=-4.5,ymax=1.2,ymin=0,enlargelimits=false,axis lines=center,width=12cm, height=3cm]
        \foreach \ox/\oy in {-3.6/0.15,-2.4/0.1,-1.2/0.6,0/1,3.6/0.15,2.4/0.1,1.2/0.6}{ 
            \foreach \p [evaluate=\p as \p using \p+\ox,evaluate=\p as \m using \ox,evaluate=\oy]in {-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4}{ 
                \addplot[domain=-5:5, fill=blue, samples=100,fill opacity=0.5]{\oy*((x+\p)>-0.2 && (x+\p)<0.2)*abs(sin(180*(x+\m))/(pi*(x+\m)))};
            } 
        }
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

PS: I also have the dirac comb as a function of x, but I already replaced it by the list to reduce computation power.

[image: picture with 100 samples]

Comment: This seems to compile fine for me with an updated TeXLive2014. I don't know how to check what the `main_memory` setting is for sure, but the `/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf.cnf` file that I have has the setting `main_memory = 10000000` which is larger than the default, but a _lot_ less that what you seem to be using.

Comment: This compiles fine for me too, but I want to increase the number of samples by a factor of 10.

I am using TexStudio. Are other compilers better in terms of memory?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to compile the plot with LuaLaTeX, with `samples=1000`; of course it took a *long* time, but LuaTeX dynamically allocates the main memory.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \begin{axis}[xmax=4.5,xmin=-4.5,ymax=1.2,ymin=0,enlargelimits=false,axis lines=center,width=12cm, height=3cm]
        \foreach \ox/\oy in {-3.6/0.15,-2.4/0.1,-1.2/0.6,0/1,3.6/0.15,2.4/0.1,1.2/0.6}{ 
            \foreach \p [evaluate=\p as \p using \p+\ox,evaluate=\p as \m using \ox,evaluate=\oy]in {-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4}{ 
                \addplot[domain=-5:5, fill=blue, samples=1000,fill opacity=0.5]{\oy*((x+\p)>-0.2 && (x+\p)<0.2)*abs(sin(180*(x+\m))/(pi*(x+\m)))};
            } 
        }
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Since you probably don't want to often change this plot, I used `standalone` so to produce a PDF that can be included as image.

Here's the `time` response:

```
  144.74 real       144.48 user         0.21 sys
```

which means more than two minutes. According to the system statistics, running the process required about 180 MB of memory.

[image]